# Learning mainframe & JCL with Java/OOP/SQL background

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I've been coding and managing Java & ASP.Net applications & servers for my entire career. Now I'm being directed towards involvement in mainframes, ie z/OS & JCL, and I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around it (they still talk about punch cards!). What's the best way to go about learning all this after having been completely spoilt by modern luxuries?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no punch cards in modern mainframes, they're just having you on.

You will have a hard time since there are still many things done the "old" way.

- Data sets are still allocated with properties such as fixed-block-80, variable-block-255 and so on. Plan your file contents.
- No directories. There are levels of hierarchy and they're limited to 8 characters each.
- The user interface is ISPF, a green-screen text-mode user interface from the seventh circle of hell for those who aren't used to it.
- Most jobs will still be submitted as batch jobs and you will have to monitor their progress with SDSF (sort of task manager).

That's some of the bad news, here's the good news:

It has a USS subsystem (UNIX) so you can use those tools. It's remarkably well integrated with z/OS. It runs Java, it runs Websphere, it runs DB2 (proper DB2, not that little Linux/UNIX/Windows one), it runs MQ, etc, etc. Many shops will also run z/VM, a hypervisor, under which they will run many LPARs (logical partitions), including z/OS itself (multiple copies, sometimes) and zLinux (SLES/RHEL).

The mainframe is in no danger of disappearing anytime soon.  There is still a large amount of work being done at the various IBM labs around the world and the 64-bit OS (z/OS, was MVS, was OS/390, ...) has come a long way. In fact, there's a bit of a career opportunity as all the oldies that know about it are at or above 55 years of age, so expect a huge suction up the corporate ladder if you position yourself correctly.

It's still used in the big corporations as it's the only thing that can be trusted with their transactions - the z in System z means zero downtime and that's not just marketing hype.  The power of the mainframe lies not in it's CPU grunt (the individual processors aren't that powerful but they come in books of 54 CPUs with hot backups, and you can run many books in a single System z box) but in the fact that all the CPU does is process instructions.

*Everything* else is offloaded to specialist processors, zIIPs for DB2, zAAPs for Java workloads, other devices for I/O (and I/O is where the mainframe kills every other system, using fibre optics and *very* large disk arrays).  I wouldn't use it for protein folding or genome sequencing but it's ideal for where it's targeted, massively insane levels of transaction processing.

As I stated, z/OS has a UNIX subsystem and z/VM can run multiple copies of z/OS and other operating systems - I've seen a single z800 box running tens of thousands of instances of RHEL concurrently. This puts all the PC manufacturers 'green' claims to shame and communications between the instances is blindingly fast with HyperSockets (TCP/IP but using shared memory rather than across slow network cables (yes, even Gigabit Ethernet crawls compared to HyperSockets (and sorry for the nested parentheses :-))).

It runs Websphere Application Server and Java quite well in the Unix space while still allowing all the legacy (heritage?) stuff to run as well. In fact, mainframe shops need not buy PC-based servers at all, they just plonk down a few zLinux VMs and run everything on the one box.

And recently, there's talk about that IBM may be providing xSeries (i.e., PCs)  plugin devices for their mainframes as well. While most mainframe people would consider that a wart on the side of their beautiful box, it does open up a *lot* of possibilities for third-party vendors.  I'm not sure they'll ever be able to run 50,000 Windows instances but that's the sort of thing they seem to be aiming for (one ring to rule them all?).

If you're interested, there's a System z emulator called Hercules which I've seen running at 23 MIPS on a Windows box and it runs the last legally-usable MVS 3.8j fast enough to get a feel. Just keep in mind that MVS 3.8j is to z/OS 1.10 as CP/M is to Windows XP.

To provide a shameless plug for a book one of my friends at work has written, check out [What On Earth is a Mainframe?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1409225356) by David Stephens (ISBN-13 = 978-1409225355). I found this invaluable since I came from a PC/UNIX background, and it is quite a paradigm shift. I think this book would be ideal for your particular question. I think chunks of it are available on Google Books so you can try before you buy.

Regarding JCL, there is a school of thought that only one JCL file has ever been written and all the others were cut'n'paste jobs on that. Having seen the contents of them, I can understand this. Programs like IEBGENER and IEFBR14 make Unix look, if not verbose, at least understandable.

Comment: Great answer! I have done some mainframe work in the past. It is a very interesting environment. And often misunderstood.

Comment: Regarding punch cards, they weren't putting me on. The guy who used it was on a conference call and didn't know a newb like me was there. A little googling told me that the old mainframers still use that language. I don't know what punch card translates to in modern mainframe terminology, though.

Comment: @Tim, it's probably just the fact that the members containing JCL and object files are still FB80 format, limited to 80 characters width. In fact, the object "files" passed in to the binder (linker) are still referred to as object decks (as in the old decks of punched cards that used to hold them).

Comment: I've been working on IBM mainframes for the past 25 years. I think the last time I saw a real punch card was at least 24 years ago. Sometimes you run across JCL with the ddname SYSPUNCH in it - this has nothing to do with punch cards (maybe once upon a time it did). Some of the terms used in mainframe shops is archaic - but the technology is simply awsome.

Comment: Here's a post from the Mainframe blog about two System z emulators, Hercules, mentioned by @paxdiablo and zPDT, which is not open-source: http://mainframe.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/herculean-high-end-hacking.html Date is 28 June 2011, so it is current. Good mainframe info site in general.

Answer (score 2):

You first misconception is beleiving the "L" in JCL. JCL isnt a programming language its really a static declaration of how a program should run and what files etc. it should use.

In this way it is much like (though superior to) the xml config spahetti that is used to control such "modern" software as spring, hebernate and ant.

If you think of it in these terms all will become clear.

Mainframe culture is driven by two seemingky incompatable obsessions.

1. Backward compatability. You can still run executables written and compiled in 1970. forty year old JCLs and scripts still run and work!
2. Bleeding edge performance. You can have 128 cpus on four machines in two datacentres working on a single DB2 query. It will run the latest J2EE (Websphere) applications faster than any other machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever get involved with [CICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CICS) (mainframe transaction server) on Z/OS, I would recommend the book ["Designing and Programming CICS applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926765).
It is very useful.
[alt text http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7031/designingandprogramming.gif](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7031/designingandprogramming.gif)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be involved with traditional legacy applications development, read books by Steve Eckols. They are pretty good. You need to compare the terms from open systems to mainframe which will cut down your learning time. Couple of examples
Files are called Datasets on mainframe
JCL is more like a shell script
sub programs/routines or like common functions etc...Good luck...

Answer (score -1):

The more hand holding at the beginning the better. I've done work on a mainframe as an intern and it wasn't easy even though I had a fairly strong UNIX background. I recommend asking someone who works in the mainframe department to spend a day or two teaching you the basics. IBM training may be helpful as well but I don’t have any experience with it so can’t guarantee it will. I’ve put my story about learning how to use the mainframe below for some context. It was decided that all the interns were going to learn how to use the mainframe as a summer project that would take 20% of there time. It was a complete disaster since all the interns accept me were working in non mainframe areas and had no one they could yell over the cube wall to for help. The ISPF and JCL environment was to alien for them to get proficient with quickly. The only success they had was basic programming under USS since it’s basically UNIX and college familiarized them with this. I had better luck for two reasons. One I worked in a group of about 20 mainframe programmers so was able to have someone sit down with me on a regular basis to help me figure out JCL, submitting jobs, etc. Second I used [Rational Developer for System z](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rdz/) when it was named WebSphere Developer for System z. This gave me a mostly usable GUI that let me perform most tasks such as submitting jobs, editing datasets, allocating datasets, debugging programs, etc. Although it wasn’t polished it was usable enough and meant I didn’t have to learn ISPF. The fact that I had an Eclipsed based IDE to do basic mainframe tasks decreased the learning curve significantly and meant I only had to learn new technologies such as JCL not an entirely new environment. As a further note I now use ISPF since the software needed to allow Rational to run on the mainframe wasn’t installed on one of the production systems I used so ISPF was the only choice. I now find that ISPF is faster then Rational Developer and I’m more efficient with it. This is only because I was able to learn the underlying technology such as JCL with Rational and the ISPF interface at a later date. If I had to learn both at once it would have been much harder and required more one on one instruction.